# Launchpad could not import your OpenPGP key

Tags: application-development, launchpad, gnupg, quickly

Quickly generated a gpg key for me:

```
quickly share
Get Launchpad Settings
The authorization page:
 (https://launchpad.net/+authorize-token?oauth_token=*******&allow_permission=DESKTOP_INTEGRATION)
should be opening in your browser. Use your browser to authorize
this program to access Launchpad on your behalf. 

Waiting to hear from Launchpad about your decision...
Launchpad connection is ok
It seems you don't have a gpg key on your computer. Do you want to create one (this may take a while)? y/[n]: y

Not enough random bytes available.  Please do some other work to give
the OS a chance to collect more entropy! (Need 282 more bytes)
*********.+++++
+++++
gpg: key **** marked as ultimately trusted
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   1  signed:   0  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 1u
Your gpg key has been create. You have to upload it to Launchpad. Guidance is provided in Launchpad help. Press any key once done
```

But when I paste fingerprint to lauchpad, it says:

> Launchpad could not import your OpenPGP key
>
> Did you enter your complete fingerprint correctly? (Help with
>   fingerprints) Is your key in the Ubuntu keyserver yet? You may have to
>   wait between ten minutes (if you pushed directly to the Ubuntu key
>   server) and one hour (if you pushed your key to another server). (Help
>   with publishing keys)

I tried with both, fingerprint from `Passwords and keys` (gui) and one from `gpg --fingerprint` and still same error. I noticed one from gui have one blank space more then one pasted from CLI. I waited more then 16 hours, but still getting same error?

Any idea?

Comment: Did you upload your key to the keyservers first? What's the key ID?

Comment: Ah, thanks. Now I uploaded it. Now all is left to do is wait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you can import your key to Launchpad, it must be available on the Ubuntu keyserver.

> ### Publishing your key
>
> Your key is useful only if other people can verify items that you
>   sign. By publishing your key to a keyserver, which acts as a directory
>   of people's public keys, you can make your public key available to
>   anyone else.
>
> **Before you add your key to Launchpad, you need to push it to the
>   Ubuntu keyserver.**
>
> Using Passwords and Encryption Keys
>
> Step 1 Open Passwords and Encryption Keys.
>
> Step 2 Select the My Personal Keys tab, select your key.
>
> Step 3 Select Remote > Sync and Publish Keys from the menu. Choose the
>   Sync button. (You may need to add hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com to your
>   key servers if you are not using Ubuntu.)
>
> It can take up to thirty minutes before your key is available to
>   Launchpad. After that time, you're ready to import your new key into
>   Launchpad!

From: https://launchpad.net/+help-registry/openpgp-keys.html#publish